# PyMC3 PK modelling. Model cant resolve to parameters used to create the data set

Tags: bayesian, pymc, pymc3

I am new to PK modelling and pymc3, but I have been playing around with pymc3 and trying to implement a simple PK model as part of my own learning. Specifically a model that captures this relationship...

[image: Simple pk]

Where C(t)(Cpred) is concentration at time t, Dose is the dose given, V is Volume of distribution, CL is clearance.

I have generated some test data (30 subjects) with values of CL =2 , V=10, for 3 doses 100,200,300, and generated data at timepoints 0,1,2,4,8,12, and also included some random error on CL (normal distribution, 0 mean, omega =0.6) and on the residual unexplained error DV = Cpred + sigma, where sigma is normally distributed the SD =0.33. In addition I have included a transformation on C and V with respect to the weight (uniform distribution 50-90) CLi = CL * WT/70; Vi = V * WT/70.

```
# Create Data for modelling
np.random.seed(0)
# Subject ID's
data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,31), columns=['subject'])
# Dose
Data['dose'] = np.array([100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,
                    200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,
                    300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300])
# Random Body Weight
data['WT'] = np.random.randint(50,100, size =30)
# Fixed Clearance and Volume for the population
data['CLpop'] =2
data['Vpop']=10
# Error rate for individual clearance rate
OMEGA = 0.66
# Individual clearance rate as a function of weight and omega
data['CLi'] = data['CLpop']*(data['WT']/70)+ np.random.normal(0, OMEGA )
# Individual Volume as a function of weight
data['Vi'] = data['Vpop']*(data['WT']/70) 

# Expand dataframe to account for time points
data = pd.concat([data]*6,ignore_index=True )
data = data.sort('subject')
# Add in time points
data['time'] = np.tile(np.array([0,1,2,4,8,12]), 30)

# Create concentration values using equation
data['Cpred'] = data['dose']/data['Vi'] *np.exp(-1*data['CLi']/data['Vi']*data['time'])
# Error rate for DV
SIGMA = 0.33
# Create Dependenet Variable from Cpred + error
data['DV']= data['Cpred'] + np.random.normal(0, SIGMA )

# Create new df with only data for modelling...
df = data[['subject','dose','WT', 'time', 'DV']]
```

Create arrays ready for model...

```
# Prepare data from df to model specific arrays
time = np.array(df['time'])
dose = np.array(df['dose'])
DV = np.array(df['DV'])
WT = np.array(df['WT'])
n_patients = len(data['subject'].unique())
subject = data['subject'].values-1
```

I have built a simple model in pymc3 ....

```
pk_model = Model()

with pk_model:
    # Hyperparameter Priors     
    sigma = Lognormal('sigma', mu =0, tau=0.01)

    V = Lognormal('V', mu =2, tau=0.01)
    CL = Lognormal('CL', mu =1, tau=0.01)    

    # Transformation wrt to weight
    CLi = CL*(WT)/70    
    Vi = V*(WT)/70

    # Expected value of outcome
    pred = dose/Vi*np.exp(-1*(CLi/Vi)*time)

    # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    conc = Normal('conc', mu =pred, tau=sigma, observed = DV)
```

My expectation was that I should have been able to resolve from the data the constants and error rates that were originally used to generate the data, although I have not been able to do this, although I can get close. In this example...

```
data['CLi'].mean()
> 2.322473543135788
data['Vi'].mean()
> 10.147619047619049
```

And the trace shows....

[image: Traceplot]

So my questions are..

1. Is my code structured correctly and are there any glaring mistakes that I have overlooked that might account for this difference?
2. Can I structure the pymc3 model to better reflect the relationship from which I have generated the data?
3. What would be your suggestions to improve the model?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question!

But I implemented a hierarchal model following the example found here...

[GLM -hierarchical](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/notebooks/GLM-hierarchical.html)

and it works a treat. Also I noticed errors in the way I was applying the errors in the dataframe - should use

```
data['CLer'] = np.random.normal(scale=OMEGA, size=30)
```

To ensure each subject has a different value for the error